# Uploading photo as a user profile's photo from Facebook Application

Tags: facebook

Is it possible for a Facebook App to submit a photo (with user's permission) as a profile photo?

Answer (score 0):

Yes see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/) it even contains sample PHP code to get you started

Comment: Thanks, but my question was how to submit a photo AS a profile photo, not TO a user profile. Doesn't seem possible...